# Poste.io - can't login by mail application - bad SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, email-server, lets-encrypt

I have a proble with poste.io and configuration with nginx-proxy. DOMAIN is valid domain :)

This is my docker-compose for poste.io:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  mailserver_posteio:

services:
  mailserver:
    image: analogic/poste.io
    container_name: poste-io
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "110:110"
      - "143:143"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
      - "995:995"
      - "4190:4190"
    environment:
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=ssl@DOMAIN
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mail.DOMAIN
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.DOMAIN
      - HTTPS=OFF
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - mailserver_posteio:/data
      - ./nginx-proxy/html/.well-known:/opt/www/.well-known # this is correct path

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

And this is configuration for nginx-proxy:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"

  dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx-proxy-gen
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro

  letsencrypt:
    restart: always
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - dockergen
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy-gen
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Almost everything works fine (I can login into dashboard with https, send and receive mail via roundcube), but I can't login to mail account by mail application like Thunderbird.

I've got error that my username or password is incorrect. I've double checked and username and password is ok.

So I login into poste.io container and in logs I found this one:

```
Oct 19 11:21:02 2d4556c1f79e dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=130.255.154.136, lip=172.18.0.2, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate: SSL alert number 42, s
ession=<e4MPbJF478OC/5qI>
Oct 19 11:21:02 2d4556c1f79e dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=130.255.154.136, lip=172.18.0.2, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate: SSL alert number 42, s
ession=<WUscbJF48MOC/5qI>
Oct 19 11:21:19 2d4556c1f79e dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=130.255.154.136, lip=172.18.0.2, session=<ZYgVbZF49MOC/5qI>
Oct 19 11:21:35 2d4556c1f79e dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=130.255.154.136, lip=172.18.0.2, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate: SSL alert number 42, s
ession=<4qwFbpF4+MOC/5qI>
```

So I logged into dashboard and clicked button to get TLS Certificate. After that I can see in dashboard in log section this:

```
[2018-10-19 10:55:08] LEScript.INFO: Account already registered. Continuing.
[2018-10-19 10:55:08] LEScript.INFO: Starting certificate generation process for domains
[2018-10-19 10:55:08] LEScript.INFO: Requesting challenge for mail.DOMAIN
[2018-10-19 10:55:08] LEScript.INFO: Sending signed request to /acme/new-authz
[2018-10-19 10:55:09] LEScript.INFO: Got challenge token for mail.DOMAIN
[2018-10-19 10:55:09] LEScript.INFO: Token for mail.DOMAIN saved at /opt/www//.well-known/acme-challenge/jIWGGbQdxk5GDjpqRaZ0ZJVnJTJZFLrz1xqkV6sQV3Q and should be available at http://mail.DOMAIN/.well-known/acme-challenge/jIWGGbQdxk5GDjpqRaZ0ZJVnJTJZFLrz1xqkV6sQV3Q
[2018-10-19 10:55:09] LEScript.INFO: Sending request to challenge
[2018-10-19 10:55:09] LEScript.INFO: Sending signed request to https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/aMXIOU7RCsAynJEYLJqKvT2WkcA_1tB7dR76yOjEh6E/8431476684
[2018-10-19 10:55:10] LEScript.INFO: Verification ended with status: valid
[2018-10-19 10:55:10] LEScript.INFO: Sending signed request to /acme/new-cert
```

**How can I resolve it ?**

**The weirdest is issue appear from 2.0.16 version. On 2.0.15 everything works !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Solution is use external volume for well-known.
After that in Poste.io attach external volume to

```
well-known:/opt/www/.well-known
```

And

```
well-known:/usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known
```

For each nginx container.

After that you can call TLS certificate for Poste.io .

Comment: your wording here is unclear.